# readxl (import excel file to R) error

Tags: r, excel, import, error-handling

When I typed the following line using readxl package, : 
bluedata <- read_excel("data.xlsx", coffee)

I get the following error: 
Error in standardise_sheet(sheet, range, sheets_fun(path)) : 
  object 'coffee' not found

What I want was to import the data in "coffee" sheet of the "data.xlsx" file.
Could any one help me to solve this problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: You probably should read more on R basics.This should work `read_excel("data.xlsx",  "coffee")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Error: object '<myvariable>' not found" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886839/what-does-error-object-myvariable-not-found-mean)

Comment: Mr. Kolyadin,  I tryed typing read_excel("data.xlsx", "coffee"). But then I get the following error    Error in sheets_fun(path) : 
  Evaluation error: zip file 'data.xlsx' cannot be opened.

Answer (score 2):

It is cool that you are using readxl package, this is faster than normal way to read outside data.

I think you can find the answer yourself by typing

```
help("read.excel")
```

or

```
?"read.excel"
```

I can tell you the answer, but you will met thousands of another problem if you can not find answer on your own