# How to fix "Object not found " error in R

Tags: r

In R studio I have imported one .csv file which has two columns X and Y.
But when I try to use `plot(X,Y)`, I get the error message:

```
"Object X not found"
```

Comment: Hey Ashish! Could you post some sample code?

Comment: Your data is most probably stored as a data.frame. Try `plot(Y ~ X, data = name_of_dataframe)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886839/what-does-error-object-myvariable-not-found-mean (there's no additional useful information here). It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Alex's answer above is correct. The `plot()` function is complaining that **X** is not a variable, and you've already said it was a column instead. The "data" parameter tells plot not to try and interpret **X** and **Y** as variables, but as columns of a dataframe.

It would also work to use

```
plot(<name_of_dataframe>$X ~ <name_of_dataframe>$Y)
```

Where you replace `<name_of_dataframe>` with the actual name of the object that you imported the `.csv` into.