# 'Object [x] not found' When Testing a Custom Formula

Tags: r

I am currently working on a project to calculate potential revenue under a variety of different parking rate structures for parking garages.

I have created a couple of custom functions to help with the analysis but am having an issue when setting a value of "0" to some of the input variables.

The main function in question is "pot_revenue_calc", but I have included the other functions as well for reference. Under each function I have also set up a simple test to run.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886839/what-does-error-object-myvariable-not-found-mean), but I did not find it helpful for my problem.

**Function (number_of_weeks)**

```
#Number of Weeks Function
number_of_weeks <- function (mins, num_days) {

  week_count <- 0

  while (mins - (num_days*1440) >= 0) {
    mins <- mins - (7*1440)
    week_count <- week_count + 1
  }

  return(week_count)
}

num_of_weeks <- Vectorize(number_of_weeks)

#test1 <- num_of_weeks(19000, 6)
#test1
```

**Function (number_of_full_days)**

```
#Number of Full Days Function
number_of_full_days <- function (mins, num_days, rollover = TRUE, weekly_rate = 0) {

  day_count <- 0

  if (weekly_rate != 0) {

    week_count <- number_of_weeks(mins, num_days)

    mins_minus_weeks <- mins - (week_count*7*1440)

    if (rollover == TRUE) {

      day_count <- max(floor(mins_minus_weeks/1440),0)

    } else {

      day_count <- max(ceiling(mins_minus_weeks/(1440)),0)

    }

  } else {

    if (rollover == TRUE) {

      day_count <- max(floor(mins/1440),0)

    } else {

      day_count <- max(ceiling(mins/(1440)),0)

    }

  }

  return(day_count)
}

num_of_full_days <- Vectorize(number_of_full_days)

test2 <- number_of_full_days(mins = 19000, num_days = 6, weekly_rate = 0)
test2
```

**Main Function (pot_revenue_calc)**

```
#Calculate Revenue Function
pot_revenue_calc <- function(mins, 
                    gp, 
                    fh_rate, 
                    inc, 
                    inc_rate, 
                    weekly_rate, 
                    num_days, 
                    dmax, 
                    rollover = TRUE) 
  {

mins_remain <- mins

if (mins <= gp) {

  pot_revenue <- 0

} else {

  if (rollover == TRUE) {

    if (weekly_rate != 0) {
      pot_revenue <- weekly_rate*num_of_weeks(mins, num_days)
      mins_remain <- mins_remain - (num_of_weeks(mins, num_days)*7*1440)

      pot_revenue <- pot_revenue + (number_of_full_days(mins, num_days, weekly_rate)*dmax)
      mins_remain <- mins_remain - (number_of_full_days(mins, num_days, weekly_rate)*1440)

      if (fh_rate != 0) {
        pot_revenue <- pot_revenue + min(fh_rate + max((ceiling((mins_remain-60)/inc)),0)*inc_rate,dmax)
      } else {
        pot_revenue <- pot_revenue + min(max((mins_remain/inc),0)*inc_rate,dmax)
      }

    } else {

      pot_revenue <- pot_revenue + (number_of_full_days(mins, num_days, weekly_rate)*dmax)
      mins_remain <- mins_remain - (number_of_full_days(mins, num_days, weekly_rate)*1440)

      if (fh_rate != 0) {
        pot_revenue <- pot_revenue + min((fh_rate + max((ceiling((mins_remain-60)/inc)),0)*inc_rate),dmax)
      } else {
        pot_revenue <- pot_revenue + min((max((mins_remain/inc),0)*inc_rate),dmax)
      }
    }

  } else {

    if (weekly_rate != 0) {
      pot_revenue <- weekly_rate*num_of_weeks(mins, num_days)
      mins_remain <- mins_remain - (num_of_weeks(mins, num_days)*7*1440)

      pot_revenue <- pot_revenue + (number_of_full_days(mins, num_days, weekly_rate, rollover = FALSE)*dmax)
      mins_remain <- mins_remain - (number_of_full_days(mins, num_days, weekly_rate, rollover = FALSE)*1440)


    } else {

      pot_revenue <- pot_revenue + (number_of_full_days(mins, num_days, weekly_rate, rollover = FALSE)*dmax)
      mins_remain <- mins_remain - (number_of_full_days(mins, num_days, weekly_rate, rollover = FALSE)*1440)

    }

  }

}

  return(pot_revenue)
}

test3 <- pot_revenue_calc(mins = 13392, gp = 10, fh_rate = 5, inc = 60, inc_rate = 3, weekly_rate = 20, num_days = 5, dmax = 25, rollover = FALSE)
test3
```

If I keep in all the variables as shown below, the function works just fine.

```
test3 <- pot_revenue_calc(mins = 13392, gp = 10, fh_rate = 5, inc = 60, inc_rate = 3, weekly_rate = 20, num_days = 5, dmax = 25, rollover = FALSE)
test3
```

However, once I assign a value of zero to a variable like "weekly_rate", I get the following error.

**Error in pot_revenue_calc(mins = 13392, gp = 10, fh_rate = 5, inc = 60,  : 
  object 'pot_revenue' not found**

Some help understanding this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to examine the logic of your function.  Depending on the values of the arguments, there are conditions where `pot_revenue` does not get created.

Comment: if rollover=FALSE and mins > gp and weekly_rate >0 you go into this statement: pot_revenue <- pot_revenue + ...

Comment: and pot_revenue is not defined...  i suggest you define all your variables at the start of the function, otherwise it's really hard to track these kind of errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how the `pot_revenue_calc` function need to behave but here are some pointers which might help you to calrify what needs to be done.

**Case 1 :**

When `weekly_rate != 0` and `mins > gp` , `pot_revenue` is first referred at this line

```
pot_revenue <- weekly_rate*num_of_weeks(mins, num_days)
```

**Case 2:**

When `mins <= gp` (irrespective of the value of `weekly_rate`), `pot_revenue` is first referred at this line

```
 if (mins <= gp) { 
    pot_revenue <- 0
 }
```

**Case 3 :**

When `weekly_rate == 0` and `mins > gp` , `pot_revenue` is first referred at this line

```
pot_revenue <- pot_revenue + (number_of_full_days(mins, num_days, weekly_rate, rollover = FALSE)*dmax)
```

You calculate `pot_revenue` using the value of `pot_revenue` which does not exist. This case needs to be fixed. Maybe remove the `if` condition from case 2 and initialize to 0 by default.

Apart from that you also don't need `if (rollover == TRUE)`, you can do `if(rollover)`.