Error: object 'calculate_lr_test' not found
when calling the function calculate_lr_test the following error appears:
Error: object 'calculate_lr_test' not found

I have installed and loaded the required package (mfp2). Is there a way to resolve this issue? Is there another function to calculate the p-values for likelihood-ratio test?

Please share the code that results in this error. See related post about the error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27886839/680068

I might be wrong; but the specified function is not exported by the package (https://github.com/EdwinKipruto/mfp2/blob/main/NAMESPACE) . The package author might use the function internally; and the function is not meant to be use that way.

However, the function can be found here and stand on a few lines,  essentially wrapping stats::pchisq()
https://github.com/EdwinKipruto/mfp2/blob/main/R/tests.R

It's a bit weird, but as @VinceGreg suggests, the calculate_lr_test() function is not exported from the package. What makes it weird is that there is a help page for the function (?mfp2::calculate_lr_test). This is inconsistent — it's normal for packages to contain internal functions that aren't meant to be accessed by the end-user, but not for those functions to be documented without any indication that they're private.
You can make use of this function by referring to it as mfp2:::calculate_lr_test (the triple-colon indicates that you want to retrieve a private function). In general accessing private functions is bad practice, but in this case it seems to make sense.
Or, as @VinceGreg also suggests, you could just define the function yourself:
function (logl, dfs) 
{
    statistic <- 2 * (logl[2] - logl[1])
    list(statistic = statistic, pvalue = pchisq(statistic, df = dfs[2] - 
        dfs[1], lower.tail = FALSE))
}

It might make sense to open an issue on the package repository about this ...

Thank you all for your useful comments. Calling the function in this way worked: mfp2:::calculate_lr_test. Also, as @VinceGreg and Ben Bolker suggested computing the p value with the pchisq function worked fine. A useful reference for this computation can be found here: https://api.rpubs.com/tomanderson_34/lrt.

If this solved your question you're encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it (I think you can do that even if the question is currently closed)
